# Playlist File Won't Stop Playing

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

One of my playlists is playing and I can't turn it off!  There's no OFF or STOP button. I put in a different CD  & it played at the same time as the other one (both playing at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

It might be a broken copy of Windows Media Player is running.

1. Close all programs.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Escape</kbd> to bring up the *Windows Task Manager*.
3. Open the **Processes** tab.
4. Click the **CPU** heading twice so that it sorts with highest CPU usage on top.
5. If one of the entries using CPU is **wmplayer.exe**, select it and press **End Process**.  It may have a different name if it isn't *Windows Media Player* that's the issue, but I'm not going to tell you to randomly start ending processes.
6. Worst case scenario, restart your computer.